# Resample daily OHLC to weekly where Friday is the first day and Thursday is the last?

Tags: pandas

I have a daily OHLC Data which needs to be converted to weekly timeframe and where Friday shall be the first day and Thursday shall be the last.

```
Open - Open of Friday
High - Highest high from Friday to Thursday
Low - Lowest low from Friday to Thursday
Close - Close of Thursday
Volume - Sum of volume from Friday to Thursday
```

I have tried writing a code for this but it is not giving me the desired output.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Jupyter\\Backtesting Project Karta\\NIFTY-I_2011.csv')

df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'],format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df.set_index(df['Datetime'],inplace=True)
ohlc_dict = {
    'Open':'first',
    'High':'max',
    'Low':'min',
    'Close':'last',
    'Volume':'sum'
    }

df.drop(columns=['Datetime','Ticker','Open Interest'],inplace=True)


final_df = df.resample('W-FRI').agg(ohlc_dict)
final_df.dropna(inplace=True)
final_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Daily dataset is as follows -

[image]

This is the output I am getting

[image]

The first line item which has 31st Dec 2010 data is Friday and the first thursday is 6th Jan 2011 which has close price of `6071`. But Close that I am getting is different. Also the high and low are not correct.

Comment: Can you test `final_df = df.resample('W-FRI', closed='left').agg(ohlc_dict)` ?

Comment: Yes, but I had to use final_df['Datetime'] = final_df['Datetime'].shift(1). Not sure why but data is showing of last week. so had to do shift (1) to date column. Thanks again

Comment: So is possible use `final_df = df.resample('W-FRI', closed='left').agg(ohlc_dict).shift('1d')` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `closed='left'`, because for `W` is default `closed='right'` in [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
final_df = df.resample('W-FRI', closed='left').agg(ohlc_dict)
```

and last:

```
final_df['Datetime'] = final_df['Datetime'].shift(1)
```

Another idea:

```
final_df = df.resample('W-FRI', closed='left').agg(ohlc_dict).shift('1d')
```